# Как можно изменять данные на сайте django?

Tags: python, база-данных, django

Есть сайт написанный на django. Для простоты описания я сделаю некоторые ремарки : в админ панели сайта есть лист(пускай "article_list") в котором хранятся все статьи. Так вот, я хочу сделать когда я пишу в консоли(не на той, где хостуется сайт) какие-то данные, допустим название статьи, это всё создавало в article_list новую статью с тем названием, которое я указывал в консоли. Какие вообще есть варианты создания статьи? Т.к. я знаю только через админ панель и через интерактивную консоль. Ещё вопрос, данный, как я выразился, лист - это является моделью или бд? Ибо я новичок в создании сайтов, не всё понимаю.

Comment: делаешь api(который принимает post запросы) ну и дальше уже можешь создавать статьи хоть через cmd хоть через postman и т.д.

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin, спасибо!